# Utilizing telnet with Ansible

Tags: ansible

Was wondering how to best utilize telnet, rather than SSH, with ansible.
We are using a Lantronix term server, and must telnet into individual ports.

More specifically, would it be best to use a specific telnet module? If so, which is most intuitive. 
Alternatively, is it more efficient to simply modify connection type within the hosts file / YAML playbook?

Comment: What did you try? Please add the attempts to the question.

Comment: Lantronix? Please provide more details. Why are you using this? `Lantronix term server, and must telnet into individual ports`

Comment: Why are you considering ansible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented [here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/plugins/connection.html), ansible does not support telnet as connection plugin. This means you cannot use ansible to connect to a remote machine via telnet and execute any of the ansible modules.

However, you can use `connection: local` for local connection(run ansible against the machine that is running it) and send [`telnet` commands](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/telnet_module.html) from the machine where ansible runs.

Example playbook will look something like that:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: my first telnet task
      telnet:
        username: user
        password: pass
        command:
          - my command
```

Comment: Where are you specifying the remote device that you are telneting to? It looks like you are just telneting the localhost.

Comment: nowhere; If you read carefuly I say "Example playbook will look something like that:"; Nowhere I even try to suggest a remote connection. I don't understand your question?

Answer (score 2):

Ansible provides a module for telnet provisioning. See:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/telnet_module.html